# Your exceeding great reward vs your reward will be great in Gen 15:1

Tags: genesis, kjv, abraham, esv

Please I need help understanding the difference in translations.

This morning while studying I stumbled on the difference in translation between ESV and KJV for Gen 15:1 where KJV States "and thy exceeding great reward" while esv states "your reward shall be very great".

I've tried checking online for why this is the case, but found nothing useful.

Please can someone help with explanations and sources to study?

PS: I am new to this.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.   Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

שְׂכָרְךָ֖ הַרְבֵּ֥ה‬ מְאֹֽד

Only הַרְבֵּ֥ה has the article. However, שְׂכָרְךָ֖ is construct which does not take an article, but the article is understood if its associated absolute has an article.  The absolute is the sufficed pronoun ךָ֖ which makes the article understood.

שְׂכָרְךָ֖ = השכר שלך

Thus, the translation, "Your reward shall be very great.”
(Gen. 15:1, JPS1985)

The implication of the meaning of שָׂכָר is that God is paying something to Abram:

> שָׂכָר ... —1. a. wages (for work)... —b. the reward that God gives Gn 15:1,... —c. שָׂכָר (parallel with פְּעֻלָּה) the reward which God has acquired for himself, which is with him ...   —2. בָּא בִשְׂכָרוֹ the damages go against his wages Ex 22:14, see Noth ATD 5:138, 150.
> —3. a. payment for a journey by sea Jon 1:3; —b. expense, maintenance Zech 8:10.
> —4. expressions involving meanings 1 and 3; for those involving 2 see above: with בּוֹא (עַל־שְׂכָרִי) ...
> --
> Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., p. 1331). E.J. Brill.